# Select a row and transpose into one cell

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a contact list with which has multiple email ids (one or more) for a particular selection. I would like to built a macro which would first select the row and then transpose all email ids from seperated by ; so that i can use the data for mail merge. Appreciate your support on this.

I would like to build a macro which will enable me to select one row and transpose all the email ids from the row into one column which are seperated by ;.

Comment: Hello and welcome to S.O. please note that this is note a free writing code. You have told you what you would like to achieve. You now need to show us the code you have developed so far and explain the exact problem you are facing with it in order for us to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Found out on the net.

```
Sub SingleCellAddress()
'Add Semicolon and combine cells in range into one selected cell, seperated by a semicolon and a space

Dim i As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, drng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.Selection
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Select a range to combine into a single cell.", rng.Address, Type:=8)
    If Err.Number = 424 Then          'Handle cancel button
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set drng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to combine", "Select a cell to combine into single cell seperated by a Semicolon", Type:=8)
    If Err.Number = 424 Then          'Handle cancel button
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If

For Each cl In rng
i = i & cl & "; "
Next cl
Range(drng.Address).Value = Trim(i)

End Sub
```